# Solving a complex variable equation containing square root of hyperbolic sine function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, roots

I was wondering if anyone can explain the method of finding all of the solutions to the following equation:

[image: equation]

m,n are arbitrary natural numbers and beta and k are positive nonzero real numbers.

After eliminating the Exp[m+n] term and putting the square root on the right hand side, I do not know how should I eliminate the square root of Sinh and solve for "tau".

I know that if this was a real equation, I should check the side to be positive and square both side but have no idea how should I solve this one.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on ["avoiding no-clue questions"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933))

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Since $e^n$ is non-zero, it can be cancelled and you are left with a linear equation with unknown $\sinh \tau$

Comment: I edited the question. @5xum

Comment: How can I eliminate the square root of sinh? Would you please give detailed expression? @xxxx036

Comment: Why can I do this? It is not clear that both sides are positive or not. Doesn't this leads to missing some of the roots? @Moo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the fact that $e^{x}$ is never equal to $0$, which means that solving your equation is equivalent to solving the equation

$$-\beta + \sinh(\tau) - \sqrt{-\beta^2 + k^2\sinh(\tau)^2} = 0.$$

Now, introduce a new variable $y=\sinh(\tau)$, and notice that your equation simplifies to

$$-\beta +ky = \sqrt{-\beta^2+k^2y^2}$$

which can quite easily be solved by:

1. Squaring both sides of the equation.
2. Solving the resulting equation.
3. Checking the obtained results to see if they are also solutions to the original equation.

Once you have calculated $y$, it is easy to then obtain $\tau$ from it.

Comment: It is not clear whether both side are positive. Doesn't squaring both sides leads to miss some of the roots?@5xum

Comment: @mathstudent Squaring both sides will never lead to *missing* any roots. It can only ever lead to finding some *extra* roots, which is why step 3 is there.

Comment: @mathstudent Let me explain. Let's say you have some equation, say $f(x)=g(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ are some expression involving $x$. Then, it is always true that **if** $f(x)=g(x)$, **then** $f^2(x)=g^2(x)$. Therefore, the set of solutions to the "squared" problem $f^2(x)=g^2(x)$ must surely include all solutions to the non-squared problem $f(x)=g(x)$. The reverse is not true, i.e., there may exist a solution that solves the squared problem, but not the non-squared one. But it is impossible for a solution to solve the non-squared problem, but not the squared problem.

Comment: @mathstudent Think of a simple equation like $x=1$. The set of solutions to that problem is $\{1\}$. Squaring that equation gives the equation $x^2=1$ which has two solutions, so its set of solution is $\{1,-1\}$. Notice that $\{1\}\subseteq\{1,-1\}$.

Comment: Thank you @5xum